# How to rebuild specified widgets only in flutter

Tags: flutter

When calling onClick(), how can I prevent only WidgetOne is rebuild, while WidgetTwo is not?

```
class SomeClass extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<SomeClass> createState() => _SomeClass();
}

class _SomeClass extends State<SomeClass>{
  int _i = 0;

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return child: Column(
             children: [
               WidgetOne(i: _i),
               WidgetTwo()
           ],
    )
}

void onClick() {
    setState(() {
      i++;
    });
}
```

I add the following text, because otherwise stackoverflow is written "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." :(

Comment: It is necessary to c check `WidgetOne` and `WidgetTwo`, i mean full widget(related part). else we can't run and test the snippet. You can describe the code and include the code.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-ZG-jS5QHQ&t=5s

Answer (score 0):

A simple and fast solution is to put `WidgetOne` in `StatefulBuilder` like this:

```dart
class SomeClass extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<SomeClass> createState() => _SomeClass();
}

class _SomeClass extends State<SomeClass> {
  int _i = 0;
  Function? innerSetState;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (context, innerSetState) {
            this.innerSetState = innerSetState;
            return WidgetOne(i: _i);
          },
        ),
        WidgetTwo()
      ],
    );
  }

  void onClick() {
    innerSetState?.call(() {
      _i++;
    });
  }
}
```

Another solution is to use [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) state manager along with [Consumer](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Consumer-class.html) widget.